# changing values in dataframe in R based on criteria

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like

```
> mydata
ID  Observation X    
1      1       3    
1      2       3    
1      3       3    
1      4       3    
2      1       4    
2      2       4    
3      1       8    
3      2       8    
3      3       8
```

I have some code that counts the number of observations per ID, determines which IDs have a number of observations that meet a certain criteria (in this case, >=3 observations), and returns a vector with these IDs:

```
> vals
[1] 1 3
```

Now I want to manipulate the X values associated with these IDs, e.g. by adding 1 to each value, giving a data frame like this:

```
> mydata
ID  Observation X   
 1      1       4    
 1      2       4    
 1      3       4    
 1      4       4    
 2      1       4    
 2      2       4    
 3      1       9    
 3      2       9    
 3      3       9
```

I'm pretty new to R and am uncertain how I might do this.  It might help to know that X is constant for each ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `mydata$ID %in% vals` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` to indicate whether the ID value for each row is in the `vals` vector. When you add this to the data currently in `mydata$X`, the `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted to 1 and 0, respectively, yielding the desired result:

```
mydata$X <- mydata$X + mydata$ID %in% vals
# mydata
#   ID Observation X
# 1  1           1 4
# 2  1           2 4
# 3  1           3 4
# 4  1           4 4
# 5  2           1 4
# 6  2           2 4
# 7  3           1 9
# 8  3           2 9
# 9  3           3 9
```